# How is the black and white to color tansition being accomplished

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to find out how, when hovered over, the photos show their true colours instead of being black and white on this site: http://2010.dconstruct.org/ . I don't think it's a simple matter of having two versions of the image, but I'm really not sure.

I'd appreciate any help with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it does use two versions of the image, even without looking at the code, you can tell by the difference in contrast some of them have between bw/colour versions.
Anyways, each anchor has the same backgroud image assigned `url("../../i/speakers/sprite.jpg")` whose different vertical position determines which portrait is shown. This sprite image is in b/w.

Each anchor contains an image element (the colored version) with an opacity initially set to 0, then set to 100% on mouse over.

```
<a class="tile bridle" href="/speakers/james-bridle">
 <p>
  <span>
   James
   <b>Bridle</b>
  </span>
 </p>
 <img alt="" src="http://media02.dconstruct.org/2010-0008/i/speakers/bridle.jpg?0008"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're exactly correct. Thanks again for sorting through it!

Comment: @Tony You're welcome!

P.S.: You can use Firebug extension for Firefox to quickly sort out this kind of doubts.. I use it all the time and I love it!

Comment: I'll definitely give it a go the next time I go poking around someone else's code!

Answer (score 4):

It uses this option to achieve transition:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 
     from(transparent), color-stop(0.7, transparent), 
     to(rgba(0, 22, 9, 0.496094)));
```